# LINQ Group By using multiple criteria

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, grouping

How would I go about grouping a list of objects by two different fields?

e.g.

```
struct Item
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public int Score;
}

List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new Item(){ "Jeff", 35, 50};
items.Add(new Item(){ "Annie", 22, 45};
items.Add(new Item(){ "Pierce", 60, 90};
items.Add(new Item(){ "Pierce", 60, 10};
items.Add(new Item(){ "Abed", 28, 22};
items.Add(new Item(){ "Troy", 22, 45};
items.Add(new Item(){ "Troy", 22, 65};
items.Add(new Item(){ "Troy", 22, 80};
items.Add(new Item(){ "Troy", 21, 2};
items.Add(new Item(){ "Troy", 21, 5};

var grouped = items.GroupBy(/*Group by age then name*/);
```

grouped would then be:

```
"Troy", 21, 2
"Troy", 21, 5

"Annie", 22, 45

"Troy", 22, 80
"Troy", 22, 65
"Troy", 22, 45

"Abed", 28, 22

"Jeff", 35, 50

"Pierce", 60, 90
"Pierce", 60, 10
```

Most solutions I've found deal with creating a new anonymous type, but that would surely lose the "Score" field.

How do I create a grouping of the original objects where the objects are grouped by multiple criteria?

Comment: Grouping by new anonymous type doesn't cause you to lose any field. How did you try the grouping and accessing "Score" field?

Comment: har07 is right that had you tried this you would have probably found that it does what you want. If you find a lot of solutions telling you that method X works then its probably worth trying even if you think it won't work (especially if its quick) because chances are you wouldn't have found so many people saying it if it was wrong.

Comment: Ah I see, it wasn't initially letting me do this when I tried. I think I must have incorrectly set something up in my LINQ afterwards then. Thanks for the clarification. EDIT: Checked what I'd done, I think I had a rogue .Select() taking place on the wrong side of some brackets, which was projecting my data to a different type.

Comment: Not sure why the down votes.  Question totally makes sense to me and I'm in the exact same spot of trying to figure this out myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var grouped = items.GroupBy(item => new { item.Name, item.Age });
```

This will produce an `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`
where TKey is the anonymous type and the TElement is Item.
Basically, this is an IEnumerable of IEnumerable.

You can access them with a double for-loop:

```
foreach (var group in grouped) {
    foreach(Item item in group) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Swapped this to answer as it is most detailed, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`GroupBy` method returns a collection of `IGrouping<(Of <(TKey, TElement>)>)` objects, one for each distinct key that was encountered. The key represents the attribute that is common to each value in the `IGrouping<(Of <(TKey, TElement>)>)` and can be accessed using a `ForEach` loop.

```
  var qry = items.GroupBy(item => new { item .Age, item .Name },
           (key, group) => new
           {
               Key1 = key.Age,
               Key2 = key.Name,
               All = group.ToList()
           });
```

You can check the result with this:

```
qry.ToList().ForEach(x => x.All.ForEach(y=>Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}",y.Name, y.Age, y.Score)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var grouped = items.GroupBy(item => item new{ item.Name, item.Age });
```

You will not loose the Score field. sublists of grouped list will still be of type Item and objects of anonymous type will be in Key property of each group.